# Help install software and using wine

Tags: software-installation, wine, release-juno

I built a pc and I want to install Radeon Pro Software for Enterprise on Ubuntu 18.04.1, I search and tried to tweak the files but it did not work and also I don't know how to use wine as the instructions varies.

Comment: have you configured wine?

Comment: I have no idea.

Comment: I think I install a program, now I need to know how to run it, if I can find it first.

Answer (score 0):

I do not really understand what you want to do very well. if you intend to install the software "(driver)" from amd en wine, I regret to tell you that it will not work, if what you want to install is the driver provided by amd you should do this:

Download the driver from the official website of amd.

Depending on the version of the driver you will need to edit the system file / etc / os-release on line 3 ID=elementary to ID=ubuntu on line 6 of VERSION_ID = "5.0" to VERSION_ID = "18.04" (open "files" with administrator privileges for to be able to make the change).

If you do not know that, it will say OS not supported.

After that open the folder where the driver is with the terminal and put there:

```
./amdgpu-pro-install -y
```

(this installs Base kernel, Accelerated graphics, Multimedia table, OpenGL Pro, Pro Vulkan, Pro OpenCL).

After installing everything correctly edit the system file / etc / os-release again, on line 3 ID=elementary on line 6 of VERSION_ID = "18.04" to VERSION_ID = "5.0" to leave that file as it was before.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_zDLT9wQHmU&t=68s

cya